# ytick pos=right doesn't work

Tags: tikz-pgf, pgfplots, positioning

[image]

This is my code:

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{tikz}
\usepackage{pgfplots}
\pgfplotsset{compat=1.3}

\begin{document}
\begin{tikzpicture}
\begin{axis}[xticklabel pos=right,
                extra y ticks = {7}, 
                extra y tick labels = {$e$},
                extra y tick style={grid=major,yticklabel pos=right}
                ]
  \addplot coordinates { (1,1) (42,23) };
\end{axis}
\end{tikzpicture}
\end{document}
```

I want, that the extra tick appears on the right hand side. But with the code above it doesn't work.

Any ideas why not?

Version:

```
This is pdfTeX, Version 3.1415926-1.40.11 (Web2C 2010)

 *File List*
 article.cls    2007/10/19 v1.4h Standard LaTeX document class
  size10.clo    2007/10/19 v1.4h Standard LaTeX file (size option)
    tikz.sty    2010/10/13 v2.10 (rcs-revision 1.76)
     pgf.sty    2008/01/15 v2.10 (rcs-revision 1.12)
  pgfrcs.sty    2010/10/25 v2.10 (rcs-revision 1.24)
everyshi.sty    2001/05/15 v3.00 EveryShipout Package (MS)
  pgfrcs.code.tex
 pgfcore.sty    2010/04/11 v2.10 (rcs-revision 1.7)
graphicx.sty    1999/02/16 v1.0f Enhanced LaTeX Graphics (DPC,SPQR)
  keyval.sty    1999/03/16 v1.13 key=value parser (DPC)
graphics.sty    2009/02/05 v1.0o Standard LaTeX Graphics (DPC,SPQR)
    trig.sty    1999/03/16 v1.09 sin cos tan (DPC)
graphics.cfg    2010/04/23 v1.9 graphics configuration of TeX Live
  pdftex.def    2011/01/28 v0.05d Graphics/color for pdfTeX
  pgfsys.sty    2010/06/30 v2.10 (rcs-revision 1.37)
  pgfsys.code.tex
pgfsyssoftpath.code.tex    2008/07/18  (rcs-revision 1.7)
pgfsysprotocol.code.tex    2006/10/16  (rcs-revision 1.4)
  xcolor.sty    2007/01/21 v2.11 LaTeX color extensions (UK)
   color.cfg    2007/01/18 v1.5 color configuration of teTeX/TeXLive
 pgfcore.code.tex
pgfcomp-version-0-65.sty    2007/07/03 v2.10 (rcs-revision 1.7)
pgfcomp-version-1-18.sty    2007/07/23 v2.10 (rcs-revision 1.1)
pgffor.sty    2010/03/23 v2.10 (rcs-revision 1.18)
pgfkeys.sty    
pgfkeys.code.tex
pgffor.code.tex
tikz.code.tex
pgfplots.sty    2010/07/14 Version 1.4.1 (git show 1.4.1-1-g64c9e95 )
supp-pdf.mkii
pdftexcmds.sty    2011/04/16 v0.15 Utilities of pdfTeX for LuaTeX (HO)
infwarerr.sty    2010/04/08 v1.3 Providing info/warning/message (HO)
ifluatex.sty    2010/03/01 v1.3 Provides the ifluatex switch (HO)
 ltxcmds.sty    2011/04/18 v1.20 LaTeX kernel commands for general use (HO)
   ifpdf.sty    2011/01/30 v2.3 Provides the ifpdf switch (HO)
epstopdf-base.sty    2010/02/09 v2.5 Base part for package epstopdf
  grfext.sty    2010/08/19 v1.1 Managing graphics extensions (HO)
kvdefinekeys.sty    2011/04/07 v1.3 Defining keys (HO)
kvoptions.sty    2010/12/23 v3.10 Keyval support for LaTeX options (HO)
kvsetkeys.sty    2011/04/07 v1.13 Key value parser (HO)
etexcmds.sty    2011/02/16 v1.5 Prefix for e-TeX command names (HO)
epstopdf-sys.cfg    2010/07/13 v1.3 Configuration of (r)epstopdf for TeX Live
```

Comment: It works for me.

Comment: I didn't get any error message, it just not work. Hope that any body else met this problem before. :/

Comment: Works for me too.

Comment: [Welcome to TeX.SE](http://meta.tex.stackexchange.com/questions/1436/welcome-to-tex-sx).  There is probably some issu the the version of the packages you are using. Add `\listfiles` _before_ `\begin{document}` and add the output from that to your question so we can compare.  You should also upload an image of the result you get.  Also, what version are you using? Have you updated your packages lately?

Comment: I added the result i got and the files above. Thanks for the reply

Comment: As @PeterGrill said, your pgfplots version is out of date (1.4.1). Update it and retry.